# Spring Boot Packaging war file run with One or more Filters failed to start

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-security

i want run my application on tomcat,so i update some code
in pom.xml,change jar to war and exclusion embedded tomcat and add servlet-api.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

extends SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AppApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AppApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(AppApplication.class).web(true);
}
}
```

and then i got this error

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name 
[xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomerFilterSecurityInterceptor/customerInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] 
is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [xxx.xxx.xxx.filter.CustomerFilterSecurityInterceptor].
```

first，i thought it's maybe the tomcat version's problem , so i update the tomcat to 8.5.12, and it's not work.

btw:when i package a jar file ,it's fine,i use jdk1.8 ,and spring boot 1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: class CustomerFilterSecurityInterceptor has extends AbstractSecurityInterceptor and implement Filter,class CustomerInvocationSecurityMetadataSource has implemnet FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource

Comment: hey @paul... did u find the solution to this problem? i am stuck with similar situation